# K6 auth0 (429 errors)

Tags: rest, load-testing, auth0, k6, http-status-code-429

I recently use K6 for ouu API load testing, but unfortunately I'm blocked with auth0 (429 error ), I need to know if it's possible to set a session feature like pytest ? obtain an access token one time and pass it to all the iterations ?

Thanks a lot for help

Try to use a session fetaure as pytest, I'm not able to perform a mock of auth0 server we have 10 servives which use auth0 access token

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.